# Difference between Execute Around Method and Template Pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

I was trying to implement some of the GoF design patterns using Java 8 Lambdas. During this exercise, I came across the Execute Around Method (EAM) pattern and the Template Pattern. Both seem to have striking similarities.

I have read that the EAM is more of an idiom without inheritance and most examples seem to be around handling resources(open, doSomething,close) as compared to the Template pattern which uses inheritance.

On reading further, I see that EAM seems to have history in Smalltalk.

However, using Java 8 Lambdas, we can actually get rid of the inheritance in the Template Pattern and simply pass behavior. The solution to implement EAM idiom is very similar to Template design pattern. One could view the open,doSomething,close as a Template pattern too, open() and close() being the same steps but doSomething() being subclassed. Using Java 8 Lambdas , we could simply pass the behavior of doSomething to a function which accepts a java.util.function.Consumer. This can be seen both as a EAM and as a Template pattern.

So my question is what is the difference between the two ?

Answer (score 2):

EAM is more like as [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in GoF design patterns.
Strategy & [Template Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) Pattern both are Behavior Pattern base on Algorithm,but they are a little different.

Steps defined in class as Template Method Pattern you can't replace one of them at runtime, if you need you must replace the whole instance with another subclass instance, but with Strategy Pattern you can replace it with another strategy instance.

Strategy Pattern more like separate each step into an individual Strategy type, Template Method is decomposing algorithm  into steps and deferring steps to subclass. but sometimes a Strategy type implemented via Template Method. for example:

### Strategy Method

```
Runnable step1 = ()->{};
Runnable step2 = ()->{};
Runnable step3 = ()->{};

play(step1,step2);
play(step3,step2); //replace step1 with step3
```

### Template Method

```
class TemplateMethod{
  void run(){
    step1();
    step2();
  }

  void step1(){}
  void step2(){}
}

class Foo extends TemplateMethod{
  void step1(){
      System.out.println("foo");
  }
}

class Bar extends TemplateMethod{
  void step1(){
      System.out.println("foo");
  }
}


TemplateMethod foo=new Foo();
TemplateMethod bar=new Bar(); 

play(foo);
play(bar);// you must replace steps with another subclass instance
```